# Permissions to see checked-in, unpublished version

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-permissions

How do SharePoint 2016 permissions allow a distinction between ordinary site users who, when they visit a page, see the published version and reviewers, whose role is to review new or updated content and supply their feedback? I tried "Approvers", but I discovered that Approvers can see the link for publishing the page. My reviewers aren't supposed to have that ability. I don't want them publishing the page, even by accident.

I came across a post here with [a similar but not identical question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18530/permissions-to-see-checked-in-but-not-published-content), but from eight years ago, concerning SharePoint 2010. I'm hoping the product has come to accommodate a greater variety of needs since then.